# How to generate standard apache log format logger python

Tags: python, apache, logging, grok, aiohttp

Can anybody help with this ??
I am writing a simple script in python. What I am trying to do is
logging the output from my script to log file in form of a standard
apache log format.

my script:

```
>>> def examine(a):
...    if a == "OK":
...       print True
...    else:
...       print False
```

examine('sasasa')
**False**

examine('OK')
**True**

Well the idea is to log the output of this function to *.log file
in the same fashion as the apache does.

So the code should keep going on like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('name_of_my_application')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler('logFileName.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.info(examine('sasasa'))
```

The question is perhaps how to make a correct `formatter = logging.Formatter(...)`

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:16:05:49 -0800] "HERE is the output of my function like:  True of False" 401 12846
```

I need this because I will be applying **grok** filter at this log files to display them in ELK stack

```
COMMONAPACHELOG %{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)
COMBINEDAPACHELOG %{COMMONAPACHELOG} %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent}

# Log Levels
LOGLEVEL ([Aa]lert|ALERT|[Tt]race|TRACE|[Dd]ebug|DEBUG|[Nn]otice|NOTICE|[Ii]nfo|INFO|[Ww]arn?(?:ing)?|WARN?(?:ING)?|[Ee]rr?(?:or)?|ERR?(?:OR)?|[Cc]rit?(?:ical)?|CRIT?(?:ICAL)?|[Ff]atal|FATAL|[Ss]evere|SEVERE|EMERG(?:ENCY)?|[Ee]merg(?:ency)?)
```